# Boot keeps breaking across OSes; SSD has no bad sectors; what could it be?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, diagnostic

My friend's Lenovo Yoga Pro 2 suddenly stopped booting into Windows. I tried fixing it using a Windows repair disk, but nothing worked. I ran some official Lenovo diagnostics that came up with nothing. I installed Ubuntu and it worked fine for a while, then another problem with booting. I ran `fsck` from a LiveUSB and it worked on reboot. Was suspicious that there might be something wrong with the SSD itself, so rebooted into LiveUSB to run `badblocks` a couple of times, but it couldn't find any bad sectors.

Is it likely that this is just an issue with the SSD and that replacing it would solve our issues, or could there be an error somewhere more sinister?

Comment: So what is the problem with booting? When a system fails to boot there is more information provided than what you have given us.

Comment: Usually, yes, but here it just kind of says "ubuntu failed to boot".